# Trying to print form array or array addresses...not getting it?

Tags: c, arrays

new here, trying to learn a piece of C with the great help of you guys, this could be a basic questions here....sorry you have start from basic.

```
void main()
{

char* arr[3] = {"baba","tata","kaka"};

char* arr1[3] = {"baba1","tata1","kaka1"};

char* arr2[3] = {"baba2","tata2","kaka2"};

char** array_all[] = {arr,arr1,arr2};

printf("%s\n",*array_all[0]);

//please guide me how to access individual entity(as arr[1], arr1[2],arr3[1])      //from each array using array_all

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for.. but this is what I understand so far.

You are wanting to access the individual elements of array_all (the elements arr, arr1 and arr2)? If so then all you do is...

```
array_all[0][i];
```

Where i is the element that you want to access.

The reason for this is because the index operators ([ and ]) actually dereferences a pointer and offsets the pointer (as in adds it by some integer, i.e. you move down in memory) that you specify. I recommend reading up on pointer arithmetic if you have no clue what happens if you add a pointer by some integer.

For example:

```
int x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
// writing x[i] is the same as *(x + i)
int i = 2; // the element you wish to access
*(x + i) = 4;  // set the ith (3rd) element to 4
*(x + 1) = 43; // set the 2nd element to 43

// Therefore...
// x now stores these elements:
// 1, 43, 4

// proof: print out all the elements in the array
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
   printf("x[%i]=%i\n", i, x[i]);
}
```

Also, writing x[0] is the same as writing *x, since the array name actually points to the first element of the array.

OH and one thing, main should actually return an integer result. This is mainly used for error checking in your program, 0 usually means no error occurred and every other error-code (number other than 0) is some specific error related to your program, that you can choose.
i.e.

```
int main()
{
   // e.g. for an error code
   /*
   if(someErrorOccured)
   {
      return SOME_ERROR_OCCURED_RETURN_VALUE;
   }
   */
   return 0; // this is at the end of the function, 0 means no error occured
}
```

Comment: Thanks miguel.martin...your efforts appreciated. I liked the way you explained it. Thanks my friend.

Comment: @studyembedded You should up vote and accept this answer if it is the most helpful to you.

Comment: Excellent detailed explanation of array indexing!  However, given that the OP's username is `studyembedded`, your 'one thing' at the end might be inapplicable as there's no OS to return to. In this case, it's often more useful to conclude main with a `while(1);` (or run the continuous task in a `while(1)` loop) so that a debugger can inspect the state of the system after the task is done.

Comment: @studyembedded - If you're running this program on a system with an OS, then yes, you should return an `int` from main.  If not, I usually use `-Wno-main` (with GCC) to remove the warning about main's return type from the compilation output.  Search for `main` on [the warning-options page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

change your printf statement line with this..

```
printf("%s\n",array_all[i][j]);
```

In place of i keep your array number and in place of k give your required element number. It works.

Comment: Do you mean "in place of *j*"?